# JFace's TreeViewer - Strange alignment on first column

Tags: alignment, jface, treeviewer

I use a TreeViewer. I do not understand why the first column of my table has an empty space on the left. This does not depend on the column, because if I change the first column, the gap is still there. The second column is well left-aligned.

SC01 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/veooL.png

SC02 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEDs2.png

Comment: TreeViewer or TableViewer? - you say different things in the title and body of the question.

Comment: TreeViewer, title modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is space left for the tree expand / collapse twistie image. The space is always reserved even if you have no children for the tree nodes.

If you don't have any children then use `TableViewer`.

Comment: Ok but it affects only the first column.

Comment: There is only one expand / collapse image per row, in the first column.

Comment: The solution to remove this space is to change TreeViewer to TableViewer or is there another way ?